# Editing Javascript files on Chrome Developer Console not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow) on how to get my Javascript changes to save, and my changes are indeed "saved", in that I can see the changes when I reload the website. Despite this, the saved changes are not actually run, and do not seem to even exist in the website's mind, since an error that had occurred on Line XYZ still does, despite the code on Line XYZ being shifted down.

I also saw something about the code not running if it was prettified. I cannot seem to unpretify it though, because the {} thing on the bottom left does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

`reolad the website` will reload all js files, so your changes will be lost. If you insert a breakpoint in line 100, and change your code after this line, your change will be executed after you stash js file and resume executing.

Comment: Oh, so are the changes I see only on the local file, and not on the actual website itself?

Comment: Also, is there a more detailed explanation on how to insert breakpoints, stash js file, etc.?